# Reason of using -Infinity in reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, infinity

So I'm reading some functional programming and there is a:

```
const max = xs => reduce((acc, x) => (x >= acc ? x : acc), -Infinity, xs);
```

Can you explain what is the exact role of **-Infinity** here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely intended to imitate the behavior of `Math.max`, which returns `-infinity` when called with no arguments:

```js
console.log(Math.max());
```

Similarly, with your `max` function, `max` called with an empty array will result in `-infinity`:

```js
const max = xs => xs.reduce((acc, x) => (x >= acc ? x : acc), -Infinity, xs);
console.log(max([]));
```

Still, it's not *that* useful in most situations, it's probably just done in order to be a conventional, predictable output when called on an empty array compared to anything else (such as throwing an error, or returning `0` or `null`).